# Como Inserir dados usando query em um loop for?

Tags: php, mysql, query, for

Estou tentando inserir dados em o DB mysql sendo que alguns dados se repetem e outros não assim quem comandaria o número de execuções seria o `for`, porém não está executando a  query dentro do for. Já fiz alguns teste de `echo` e as variáveis estão ok.

```
 $control=mysqli_query($conn,"select ifnull(max(id_controle),0)from ficha");
 $controll=mysqli_fetch_row($control);

 $ct=$controll[0];
 $ct++;

$quantidade = count($quant);

$qu.="insert into ficha (id_controle,id_pedido,id_cliente,quantidade,id-   produto,cor,valormontagem,valoracrescimo,dataentrega,datamontagem,obs)";
for ($q = 0; $q < $quantidade; $q++){

$quant[$q];
$descricao[$q];
$cor[$q];
$valorm[$q];
$idcliente;
$ct;
$pedido;
$idcliente;
$acrecimo;
$entrega;
$montagem;
$tsmg;
$qu.="values('$ct','$pedido','$idcliente','$quant','$descricao','$cor','$valorm','$acrescimo','$entrega','$montagem','$tsmg')";
$p=mysqli_query($conn,$qu);
```

}
}

Alguém pode dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na concatenação de strings.

A variável $qu está sendo usada para concatenar seu comando sql. O que acontece é o seguinte:

**Valor de $qu antes do laço**:

```
insert into ficha (id_controle,id_pedido,id_cliente,quantidade,****id-   produto****,cor,valormontagem,valoracrescimo,dataentrega,datamontagem,obs)
```

Repare no que está entre ****, possivelmente você terá um erro no comando sql, verifique o nome da coluna.

**Valor de $qu após a primeira iteração do laço:**

```
insert into ficha (id_controle,id_pedido,id_cliente,quantidade,****id-   produto****,cor,valormontagem,valoracrescimo,dataentrega,datamontagem,obs)values('$ct','$pedido','$idcliente','$quant','$descricao','$cor','$valorm','$acrescimo','$entrega','$montagem','$tsmg')
```

Repare que VALUES está colado com ), provavelmente você terá erro na primeira iteração mesmo.

Na segunda iteração do laço você estará juntando o valor de $qu com `values('$ct','$pedido','$idcliente','$quant','$descricao','$cor','$valorm','$acrescimo','$entrega','$montagem','$tsmg')`, resultando em:

```
insert into ficha (id_controle,id_pedido,id_cliente,quantidade,id-   produto,cor,valormontagem,valoracrescimo,dataentrega,datamontagem,obs)values('$ct','$pedido','$idcliente','$quant','$descricao','$cor','$valorm','$acrescimo','$entrega','$montagem','$tsmg')values('$ct','$pedido','$idcliente','$quant','$descricao','$cor','$valorm','$acrescimo','$entrega','$montagem','$tsmg')
```

A palavra `VALUES` está se repetindo o que é incorreto na sintaxe sql, o correto deveria ser:

```
insert into ficha (id_controle,id_pedido,id_cliente,quantidade,id-   produto,cor,valormontagem,valoracrescimo,dataentrega,datamontagem,obs) values('$ct','$pedido','$idcliente','$quant','$descricao','$cor','$valorm','$acrescimo','$entrega','$montagem','$tsmg'), ('$ct','$pedido','$idcliente','$quant','$descricao','$cor','$valorm','$acrescimo','$entrega','$montagem','$tsmg')
```

E isso acontece mais e mais cada vez que o laço roda.

**Ao invés de:**

```
    $qu.="values('$ct','$pedido','$idcliente','$quant','$descricao','$cor','$valorm','$acrescimo','$entrega','$montagem','$tsmg')";

   $p=mysqli_query($conn,$qu);
```

**Tente**:

```
$p=mysqli_query($conn,$qu . " values('$ct','$pedido','$idcliente','$quant','$descricao','$cor','$valorm','$acrescimo','$entrega','$montagem','$tsmg')");
```

Desta maneira você não atribui a concatenação em $qu, note que também coloquei um espaço antes de `values`